# Blackberry Q10 can't use USB tethering

Tags: 14.04, tethering, blackberry

We have a Blackberry Q10 device we cannot use neither USB tethering to share the internet connection, nor share files with on Ubuntu 14.04.2 x64.

```
System:    Host: patrik-Lenovo-G50-45 Kernel: 3.16.0-34-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: 80E3 version: Lenovo G50-45
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Lancer 5B2 version: 31900058 STD Bios: LENOVO version: A2CN23WW(V1.05) date: 07/08/2014
CPU:       Quad core AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics (-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm) 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 1000.00 MHz 2: 1000.00 MHz 3: 1800.00 MHz 4: 1000.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics] 
           X.Org: 1.16.0 driver: fglrx Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon R4 Graphics GLX Version: 4.4.13283 - CPC 14.501.1003
Audio:     Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device 9840 driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.16.0-34-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8169 
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k 
           Card-3: Atheros 
           IF: N/A state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
```